# Applescript - How do I check if it is the first time a user has logged in on said day

Tags: macos, date, terminal, applescript

Trying to make an opening script, it greets the user depending on the time of day then asks if you would like more information on the system (how much mail and the amount of messages), my problem is I am including calendar events and I only want to say the amount of events on current day only if it is the first time logging on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The shell command `last` displays the login history.

Comment: I know that but I don't know how to check between dates

Comment: What do you mean "check between dates"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want the script to be specific to the current user, you could store a config file in the user's login directory that you write the date into each time your program runs. Then you just have to check if the date in the file is the date today.

That could go something like this in Applescript:

```
-- Get current date in format "03/05/2016"
set currentDate to short date string of (current date)

-- Specify name of our config file in HOME directory - EDIT THIS
set configFile to ((path to home folder as string) & ".yourApp")

-- See what date, if any, is currently in the file
try
   set previousContent to (read file configFile)
on error
   set previousContent to ""
end try

-- Put today's date in the file as we have run today
try
   set fileRef to open for access file configFile with write permission
   set eof of fileRef to 0
   write currentDate to fileRef starting at eof
   close access fileRef
end try

-- See if date of previous run is same as today's date
if currentDate is previousContent then
   display dialog "Not first login today"
else
   display dialog "First login today"
end if
```

Note that I intentionally have a period/dot as the first letter of the config filename (`$HOME/.yourApp`) so that it is a hidden file and doesn't show up in Finder.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if I'm reading this question correctly, but I believe you are trying to determine the difference between the last two times a person logged in.

If so, you can capture the day number of the latest two logins from a do shell script:

```
last -2 eric|cut -d" " -f28|tail -1

last -2 eric|cut -d" " -f28|tail -2|head -1
```

Will get you the day of the month of the last two logins. The obvious catch is if they logged in on 3rd of this month and the 3rd of last month.

You can add an if clause to check if the months are equal, if the days are. The 3-letter month code is in -f27 (rather than the -f28 above).

Could even start by checking the month, then if they are equal, check the days. Just store them in variables, or use ()'d statements and compare.

Example:

```
if (do shell script "last -2 " & userName & "|cut -d\" \" -f27|tail -1") is equal to (do shell script "last -2 " & userName & "|cut -d\" \" -f27|tail -2|head -1") then
   if (do shell script "last -2 " & userName & "|cut -d\" \" -f28|tail -1") is equal to (do shell script "last -2 " & userName & "|cut -d\" \" -f28|tail -2|head -1") then
      -- need to check for too few logins to compare, which will return a null string.
      if (do shell script "last -2 " & userName & "|cut -d\" \" -f28|tail -1") is not equal to "" then
         set firstLoginToday to false
      else
         set firstLoginToday to true
   else
      set firstLoginToday to true
   end if
else
   set firstLoginToday to true
end if
```

I'm curious if this is the solution to what you were attempting to do...

Comment: I am trying to make a extremely simple personal assistant on start up, it will tell me things like email count, message count and so forth, the problem I am having is the calendar event, I want it to say how many events are on said day but only if it is the first time a user has logged in; the betwee a dates was an idea to check if it was the first time logging in on that dat... Between say Tuesday and Wednesday

Comment: Then you can include the code above as a function as a test. Just change the "set" lines to "return" true or false. It will be more robust than a day of the week check which will return true if someone logs in on Tuesday, and their last login was the previous Tuesday. Of course you will also have to set "userName" appropriately; either earlier in your code or changing it to the actual user name variable you already have set, if you have one.